# Why are so many humans Force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

It *seems* to me that humans form the greater percentage of beings who use the Force.

At least in the films, there are plenty of Human Force-users (Qui-Gon Jinn, Obi-Wan Kenobi, Anakin, Mace Windu, Darth Sidious, Luke, [Leia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9077/did-princess-leia-ever-use-the-force), Count Dooku), not to mention all the human younglings we see compared to the number of non-humans. Even if humans don't make up the majority of Force users, it seems that more humans than any other *one* species are Force-sensitive.

For example, I have listed **eight** humans above.  In canon, there are some species that only have one or two.

Is there a canon explanation for why Force-sensitivity seems to be so prevalent in Humans?

Comment: It makes the makeup/effects budget cheaper.

Comment: More seriously, it also looks like humans  make up a larger proportion of species (that we see, at any rate) overall.

Comment: Maybe we are easily colonized by Midiclorians. <shudder>

Comment: OK, is there explicit evidence for or against the argument that Midiclorians favour sentient races equally, and that there are more human force users because there are simply more humans?

Comment: @anthony-arnold - there are DEFINITELY variations in per-race Force sencitivity. Except NOT usually favoring humans - there are races that are almost entirely Force sensitive. If you count quadillions of humans in the galaxy, VERY few percentage wise are Force sensitive

Comment: Right, so there must be an F-ton more humans.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Kevin said, this was simply due to the fact that [humans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Human) were numerically predominant species in Star Wars galaxy. This was both due to their expansionist nature and the fact that they were able to use Rakatan technology for rapid expansion.

However, there is a very clear notion that there is a great disparity among difference species as far as amounts of [Force Sensitivity](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force-sensitive). E.g.

- [Taung](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Taung) - the species that founded Mandalorian cluture - is not know to ever have had a Force Sensitive individual according to Wookieepedia (src: [Galaxy at War](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_at_War)).
- Humans had some ratio of Force Sensitives, not exactly known, but remember that we had a figure of 10,000 Jedi for millions of inhabited worlds. NOT really frequent.
- [Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_%28species%29) (the species that gave name to the order of Dark Jedi)

  > ... had a larger than average number of individuals with potential to use the Force in their species, so high in fact that the entire species was considered strongly Force-sensitive. (Sources: *Jedi Academy Training Manual*, *Jedi vs Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force*, [StarWars.com|Sith article](https://www.starwars.com/databank/organization/thesith/))

Comment: Just to add a few other races, Force sensitivity seemed rather rare among Wookiees and Keshiri.

Comment: Not sure if it's canon, but all Miralukans are Force-sensitive, as are all of the "yodas" that we know of. On the other hand, Force-sensitive Jawas are virtually unheard of.