# Are Force Sensitivity and Blood Lines Connected?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

This has been discussed in at least one [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/prior-to-the-introduction-of-midichlorians-was-force-adeptness-hereditary) before, but not directly addressed, at least not on this site.

Is there any actual connection between blood lines and Force sensitivity? We certainly see hints of that with both of Anakin's children showing Force sensitivity.  Do patterns like that show in other families?  Is there any indiction that Force sensitivity can be hereditary in some species or in some families?

(I'm not asking if it is *always* hereditary or always following blood lines, but is there enough to show this can be a notable factor in whether someone is sensitive or not.)

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please specify precisely which part of my answer to linked question didn't answer this one? `It was implied to be heritable (which is different from hereditary) - meaning, there's a genetic impact on Force abilities (in other words, having a Force sensitive parent increases one's chances to be a Force sensitive, but doesn't 100% correlate)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the linked question should really address this.

Force sensitivity **is observably heritable** (which is different from hereditary) - meaning, there's a genetic impact on Force abilities (in other words, having a Force sensitive parent increases one's chances to be a Force sensitive, but doesn't 100% correlate).

This is shown both by existence of Force-sensitive populations (Witches of Dathomir, for example, or Red Sith), the Skywalker/Solo family (from Anakin down to Cade), and having Jedi offspring frequently be Force-sensitive. E.g. in "Children of the Jedi", Corran Horn had a notable Jedi for grandfather (Halcyon family), numerous other examples of Jedi showing to be 1-3 generations offspring from other Jedi.

As a side note, being heritable/biological, Force Sensitivity is shown to be somewhat preserved when cloning (Joruus C'baoth, Starkiller, clone of Luke Skywalker).

Comment: I didn't feel like the answers addressed it directly - is it inherited?

Comment: @Tango - sorry, i'm not clear, are you asking about difference between inherited and heritable?

Comment: Sorry, very foggy today, due to some serious stress in meatspace.  Is it heritable?

Comment: Bolded line # 2.