# Did the Jedi code cause a reduction of the number of Force sensitive people?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

According to the answer of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/are-force-sensitivity-and-blood-lines-connected) the Force sensitivity is genetically inherited. I.e. you are more likely to be eligible for Jedi training, if your parents were.

The Jedi code forbids having children and the Jedi Order existed for several thousands of years. Did this lead to reduction of the potential Jedi / Force sensitive individuals?

Comment: Possible dupe of [If mastery of the Force is hereditary, how are the Jedi so numerous?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68250/if-mastery-of-the-force-is-hereditary-how-are-the-jedi-so-numerous?rq=1)?

Comment: I suspect that you're conflating two different questions. Becoming a Jedi increases the number of Jedi but potentially decreases the number of Force-sensitive offspring you might have.

Comment: Yes, the forbiddance drove Anakin to become a Sith and kill a bunch of Jedi.

Comment: @Null - That wasn't why he did it.

Comment: @Valorum It's a joke.

Comment: @Null That actually is why he did it, though. If his relationship with Padme wasn't forbidden then he could have gone to the Jedi for help when he had visions of her dying, rather than getting advice from a Sith.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it did not, because the Jedi weren't the only Force Users in the universe.**

The Jedi were the best known, constantly sticking their nose into galactic politics as Jedi Knights, but there was also the Sith, the Force Wielders, the Force Priestesses, the Nightsisters of Dathomir, and the Dagoyan Order.

While the "main Sith" had their rule-of-two business going on, even the "main Sith" weren't the only Sith (at least in Legends, the "Rule of Two" Sith were looked down upon by other orders of the Sith; they're mentioned in the New Jedi Order books).

Force-Sensitivity was also a variable thing;  Jedi had amazingly strong powers, but anyone could be a "little bit sensitive."  This is expanded on in the EU;  characters would have "eerily accurate premonitions" or "surprisingly fast reflexes".  They wouldn't attribute it to "The Force," but more likely to skill or luck.  But they would still carry the genes, and eventually enough "bits" of Force would stack up to cause a powerful force sensitive to appear.

Finally, depending on how you view the force, if it has a will of it's own, it would cause Force Sensitives to be born no matter what.

Comment: Still a certain number of Force sensitive people did not produce offspring. Are you saying that this number wad too small compared to the total number of Force sensitive and had too little influence in the end?

Comment: @vap78 Recall that there is apparently an age limit on receiving Jedi training, and that there are worlds, presumably many of them, where there is no way to systematically test all children while they remain young enough.  Possibly such a systematic test is considered illegal in the Republic, though given how non-chalant Qui-Gon is about conducting blood tests on children without informed consent and under the guise of a deception, maybe it''s legal after all.  Though how likely is it they can force children into training?  Likely only a small percentage enter training.

Comment: @vap78, I'm saying that everyone in the Star Wars universe is "Force Sensitive".  Whatever else you may think of midi-chlorians, Canon states that "life could not exist."  Every living being in the universe has midi-chlorians of varying amounts, and only the highest ever have enough power to become a Jedi Knight... or even appear on their radar.  All you need are two parents who are not, themselves, powerful in the force providing the genes necessary to attract a high midi-chlorian count.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy this is supposition, not backed by facts, but I've always thought the systematic testing and training of Jedi Knights was specifically because Jedi are so gosh darned powerful.  The Jedi Code and Jedi System provides the Republic a safe way to contain "superheroes" by tracking, identifying, and then training those superheroes in the Jedi way.  As a side benefit, they get a nominally deniable extrajudicial police force which polices itself (because only a Jedi really has the power to stop another rampaging Jedi).