# Were all Force wielders born from Force-sensitive parents?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Are there any records of a Force-sensitive individual being born from non-Force-sensitive parents?  Do we have any information on whether Force-sensitivity is a genetic (or genetic-like) trait?  I am looking primarily for canon sources.

Comment: @Möoz Read the last line of that question - "I'm not asking if it is always hereditary or always following blood lines".  My question is *specifically* about the necessity of force-sensitivity in the parents.

Comment: In what way does that question not answer yours?

Comment: @Möoz  **It's a different question.**  I think the last line of it is quite sufficient to tell that.  There is some useful information in the answer, but from my experience on other SE sites, answers' content should not be taken into consideration when examining duplicates.  And aside from the different tilt that question takes, it is also 5 years old, we have a lot of new information and changes to canon now.

Comment: We tend to do things differently around here. In fact, [a question _can_ be marked as a duplicate, because of answers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6944/21267). Also, It's better to clarify an existing question with new details rather than ask a different question. Also, here, age has nothing to do with duplicate-ness.

Comment: @Möoz technically yes age should have nothing to do with duplicate-ness but do you really think it would be easier and produce the same caliber and quantity of answers to try to resurrect a 5 year old question than to leave this one open?  Also the only answer there does not fully address my question again due to the fact that I am specifically looking for a link of necessity between parents' force-sensitivity and childrens'.

Comment: I've re-opened this on the grounds that the question this was closed as a duplicate of does not address the "Are there any records of a Force-sensitive individual being born from non-Force-sensitive parents?" part of the question. Also, the answer to the other question primarily uses Legends information whereas this requests canon sources. The " Do we have any information on whether Force-sensitivity is a genetic (or genetic-like) trait?" part is a duplicate, though.

Comment: Anakin Skywalker's mother was not force sensitive. Also in the canon book Ahsoka, she meets a young kid whose parents are not force sensitive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know there was a lot of such people that were born from not sensitive parents. Since the Jedi Order prohibited any form of attachment (although there were some marriages along its history like

> Revan and Bastila(Legends, but Revan could possibly be canon as I heard he was mentioned in one of Canon media) or Anakin and Padme(Canon)

having kids was probably prohibited as well. As far as we know most of the powerful Force-sensitive beings were tracked and trained to be Jedi, so most of the parents of future Jedi weren't Jedi themselves.

But this doesn't necessarily mean that they weren't Force-sensitive. Their Force sensitivity could be too weak, they were found too late to begin training, or were never found. As far as I know, Force-sensitivity is not a binary thing meaning you are or you aren't Force-sensitive. It was more fluid, depending on amount of midi-chlorians you have in your blood.

So to answer your question: There is a history of many Force users that were not born from other known Force users, specifically from Jedi. One example I know about from Star Wars Rebels:

> Ezra Bridger

We know his parents were not Jedi and there is no evidence that they were Force-sensitive. There is no evidence telling they weren't neither, although info about them in show suggests they were just a normal, regular couple, so I find it unlikely for them to be Force-sensitive.

In my opinion it is not a genetic trait and a Force-sensitive child can be born from parents who are not Force-sensitive. It may however be that Force-sensitivity has to build up through generations (in the form of midi-chlorians, which amount may be a genetic trait).

A nice question and answer about Force using skills and if it's inheritable is here: [Prior to the introduction of midichlorians, was Force adeptness hereditary?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/prior-to-the-introduction-of-midichlorians-was-force-adeptness-hereditary)

Comment: "Since Jedi Order prohibited any form of attachment" This is actually a really excellent point that I think we all forget about because "Skywalkers".

Comment: Can you find proper evidence of Ahsoka's parents? A fanon wiki with no cites and very dubious info presented is hardly good evidence. I don't recall what is described there in the show, although I may have just forgotten it.

Comment: Could you please separate the Legends info from the Disney canon info? Both are useful, but it should be clearer which is which.

Comment: "The Jedi Order prohibited any form of attachment" does *not* mean "celibacy", as Lucas himself stated. They could go whoring it up around the galaxy leaving illegitimate offspring all over the place so long as they didn't have anything to do with them after conception (or birth, if female). Which, when you think about it, is highly dysfunctional and makes it easier to understand why they thought grabbing kids from families was acceptable practice.

Comment: @Jack Sorry I don't have any more reliable source right now. I guess rewatching episodedes from clone wars could give some answers, but I can't do it for now.

Comment: @MrHutnik get rid of the section then, the link is has huge chunks fanfiction, like Ahsoka meeting the US president. While parts are obvious based on canon material, it is not credible.

Comment: @Jack Should I delete whole section or leave the information about character but delete unreliable sources?

Comment: @MrHutnik I'd probably look for a different example. Palpatine is the first that comes to mind, I don't think there is any indication that his family had any force sensitivity in either legends or disney cannon.

Comment: @Jack Found another one that is Canon(from Star Wars Rebels) I already addded it at the end, but I'll rearrange it. Please feel free to edit it further if you see any possible improvement :)

Comment: @MrHutnik, good example, I think you can just remove the Ahsoka bit for now.

Answer (score 3):

In the Phantom Menace Qui-Gon tells Shmi

"He is unlucky if he had been born in the central worlds his ability would have been identified earlier"

That suggests to me that Force users are not only born of Force Sensitive parents. If they where then it would be easy to identify them from there lineage. Instead force users are found by members of the Jedi Order seeking them out.

Spoiler regarding the last Jedi below:

> The fact also that Rey's parents are not force sensitive as well shows that it is possibly the Force that chooses who it allows to use it.

Comment: Note that your "fact" in the spoiler isn't necessarily confirmed as a fact yet.  My quest to determine its validity is actually what prompted me to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: There are other examples throughout the canon of wielders of the force not coming from force sensitive parents.