# Is the Force from Star Wars a genetically given ability or something that anyone can develop?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Or are some naturally better at it, but certain people with the right genes are able to use it better, like really powerful Jedis are mutants? I've wondered about this before and I've never had it cleared up.

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/prior-to-the-introduction-of-midichlorians-was-force-adeptness-hereditary

Comment: If it was a genetic thing (*cough* *cough* midi-chloridians), people could just isolate the genes and sell them. *"Want to become a Sith Lord and rule the galaxy? For one gene sample of midi-chloridians, just send me a million credits."*

Comment: Also see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176785/19561

Comment: midi-chloridians transfusion

Comment: This is addressed across the two duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes.

Midi-chlorians do have an influence on how strong someone is in the Force, but even Anakin would never get to use the Force to a large extent if he did not work to develop it.

Everyone has *some* midi-chlorians, since that is similar to carbon in the Star Wars universe, where life cannot exist without it. As Emperor Palpatine said:

> Darth Plagueis was a Dark Lord of the Sith, so powerful and so wise he could use the Force to influence the midi-chlorians to create life ...

Your midi-chlorian count is your *potential* with the Force, not your power. If you had a very small midi-chlorian count but worked super hard with the Force, you may be able to lift a small rock. But if you had a super high midi-chlorian count, then you can do much more powerful things *as long as you work on it.*

If you don't try, then you can't develop any powers even *if* you have a super high midi-chlorian count.

Comment: source for any of that?

Comment: Which parts specifically?

Comment: Barring the quote from the film - all of it. It reads like pure speculation - there is no source to canon or legends information. The answer is as good as fan-theory without that

Comment: @NKCampbell Sentence 5 ( If you had a very small midi-chlorian count but worked super hard with the force, you may be able to lift a small rock.) is the only sentence that is fan speculation everything else is either from a direct source, inspired from a legit source, or unimportant.

Comment: terrific - feel free to cite the direct source and lose all the speculation and unimportant stuff then as it's unnecessary and generally off-topic around here. And welcome!

Comment: @NKCampbell   Sentence 1: Irrelevant (unless you can argue otherwise). Sentence 2: Relates to sentence 4, a direct quote. Sentence 3: Relates to sentence 4, a direct quote. Sentence 4: Direct quote. Sentence 5: In "Absolutely everything you need to know about Star Wars" (I know it is a lame source, but it is relevant), it says: "The more midi-chlorians you have, the more powerful a jedi you can become. CAN, not WILL. It is obviously a measure of potential. Sentence 6: I actually mistook sentence 5 for this, so it has already been discussed. Sentence 7: You should know that this is true.

Comment: @NKCampbell    Sentence 8: Supported by sentence 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87261/discussion-between-knox-boyd-and-nkcampbell).

Comment: There is evidence for this answer in Star Wars: Rebels.